# Matlab vectorization of 3 nested for-loops

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I would like to vectorize the 3 nested for-loops in the following code:

```
    StepX=sqrt(3/2);
    StepY=sqrt(1/2);
    StepZ=sqrt(3);
    AuxX=StepX/6;
    AuxY=StepY/2;
    AuxZ=StepZ/3;

    n=1
    for i=0:L_x-1;
     for j=0:L_y-1;
      for k=0:L_z-1;
             A1(n,:)=[0+i*StepX 0+j*StepY 0+k*StepZ];  % Layer A1  
             A2(n,:)=[3*AuxX+i*StepX AuxY+j*StepY 0+k*StepZ]; %  Layer A2
             B1(n,:)=[2*AuxX+i*StepX 0+j*StepY AuxZ+k*StepZ]; % Layer B1
             B2(n,:)=[5*AuxX+i*StepX AuxY+j*StepY AuxZ+k*StepZ]; % Layer B2    
             C1(n,:)=[4*AuxX+i*StepX 0+j*StepY 2*AuxZ+k*StepZ]; % Layer C1
             C2(n,:)=[1*AuxX+i*StepX 1*AuxY+j*StepY 2*AuxZ+k*StepZ]; % Layer C2
             n=n+1;
       end
     end
    end
```

I tried to do it as follows:

```
 [A1_X,A1_Y,A1_Z] = ndgrid(0*AuxX:StepX:L_x-1,0*AuxY:StepY:L_y-1,0*AuxZ:StepZ:L_z-1);
A1 = [A1_X(:),A1_Y(:),A1_Z(:)]; % Layer A1

 [A2_X,A2_Y,A2_Z] = ndgrid(3*AuxX:StepX:L_x-1,1*AuxY:StepY:L_y-1,0*AuxZ:StepZ:L_z-1);
A2 = [A2_X(:),A2_Y(:),A2_Z(:)]; % Layer A2

[B1_X,B1_Y,B1_Z] = ndgrid(2*AuxX:StepX:L_x-1,0*AuxY:StepY:L_y-1,1*AuxZ:StepZ:L_z-1);
B1 = [B1_X(:),B1_Y(:),B1_Z(:)]; % Layer B1

 [B2_X,B2_Y,B2_Z] = ndgrid(5*AuxX:StepX:L_x-1,1*AuxY:StepY:L_y-1,1*AuxZ:StepZ:L_z-1);
B2 = [B2_X(:),B2_Y(:),B2_Z(:)]; % Layer B2

[C1_X,C1_Y,C1_Z] = ndgrid(4*AuxX:StepX:L_x-1,0*AuxY:StepY:L_y-1,2*AuxZ:StepZ:L_z-1);
C1 = [C1_X(:),C1_Y(:),C1_Z(:)]; % Layer C1

[C2_X,C2_Y,C2_Z] = ndgrid(1*AuxX:StepX:L_x-1,1*AuxY:StepY:L_y-
1,2*AuxZ:StepZ:L_z-1);
C2 = [C2_X(:),C2_Y(:),C2_Z(:)]; % Layer C1
```

It seems that I wasn't careful enough with the endpoints of each layer, so the grids were messed up. Could you please help me to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, would you mind explaining what your code is doing? That will make it easier for you to get help.

Comment: Sure, I hope that you're familiar with crystallography terms - basically it replicates a Face-Centered Cubic (FCC) pattern of atoms in a cubic crystal system when your coordinates system is aligned with the [1,1,1] plane.
Is it clear enough or do you need another simplification?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can you provide the values for `L_x`, `L_y` and `L_z`?

Comment: L_x = 80,
L_y = 20,
L_z = 20.

The code should generate 32,000 atoms in each layer (which is 80*20*20), like the for-loops version does. Thank you for helping!

Comment: the for loop solution take 3 seconds to compute, why bother vectorizing it? why do you think it'll be much faster ?

Comment: I just gave example values, which I consider to change in the future for higher orders of magnitude (i.e. 800,200,200). Hence - it takes more time to compute. Besides, I have intentions to manipulate the patterns in other ways (inserting dislocations/imperfections etc.).
In order to do all that efficiently, I prefer to vectorize the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of thinking, I came up with a simple solution:

```
StepX=sqrt(3/2);
StepY=sqrt(1/2);
StepZ=sqrt(3);
AuxX=StepX/6;
AuxY=StepY/2;
AuxZ=StepZ/3;

i = 0:L_x-1;
j = 0:L_y-1;
k = 0:L_z-1;

[I,J,K] = ndgrid(i,j,k);
A1 = [I(:)*StepX,J(:)*StepY,K(:)*StepZ];
A2 = [3*AuxX+I(:)*StepX,AuxY+J(:)*StepY,0+K(:)*StepZ];
B1 = [2*AuxX+I(:)*StepX,0+J(:)*StepY,AuxZ+K(:)*StepZ];
B2 = [5*AuxX+I(:)*StepX,AuxY+J(:)*StepY,AuxZ+K(:)*StepZ];    
C1 = [4*AuxX+I(:)*StepX,0+J(:)*StepY,2*AuxZ+K(:)*StepZ];
C2 = [1*AuxX+I(:)*StepX,1*AuxY+J(:)*StepY,2*AuxZ+K(:)*StepZ];
```

For the vectorized version it takes about 0.008 seconds for L_x=80,L_y=20 and L_z=20.
However, using the nested-loops version it takes about 1.9 seconds for the same values.